# Whats the best way to change the content urls in the WordPress Rest API results?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

Say I have api.wordpresssite.com where I will be entering data, uploading images and so on.  Then saw that I want to consume the WordPress API on another site like mysite.com.

WordPress will then assume that every link in content will be api.wordpresssite.com It will also embed images with the same URL because the links and media are absolute.

Am I supposed to process the content on mysite.com looking for links but ignoring media or is there a plugin or function that I can add to my theme to do this?

I have tried changing the base URL and while it works for links, it breaks media uploads.

There are multiple endpoints so I am thinking that even if there was a function to add, it would be too far down the line of execution to do anything.

For Example, there is the WP API, as well as JetPack, and Yoast that I am using.

There are tonnes of articles on "How to use WordPress in Laravel" but not a single article has talked about how to "normalize" the content for the site that is consuming it.

The API feels like it's only true out of the box use is to be used with some kind Javascript based front end.

*What I would like is a headless WordPress API with relative URLs for content links.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion that no one really uses the WordPress API seems to be confirmed. Mainly on an external site.

I had to create some render methods that looked for HREF links and remap them on the content, and menus.

It still seems silly and not very polished.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same answer and solved it this way:

What you would need to do is set the site URL to `www.remote-domain.com`.
You can do this by going to `WP Admin` > `Settings` > `General`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXM4U.png)

Then on your functions.php file or somewhere you can add a filter (plugin etc.) add this filter in.

```
add_filter( 'rest_url', 'fix_rest_url');
 
function fix_rest_url( $url ) {
    return $url;
}
```

Got the answer from: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49146